# How to select records based on value of some aggregate function over an integer array column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have a table `foos`:

```
╔════╤═══════════╗
║ id │ numbers   ║
╠════╪═══════════╣
║ 0  │ {1, 2, 3} ║
╟────┼───────────╢
║ 1  │ {4, 3, 6} ║
╟────┼───────────╢
║ 2  │ {7, 8, 9} ║
╚════╧═══════════╝
```

How do I write a query to select a row based on the maximum value or sum of the numbers in the array column? I'm looking to write something like, "select records whose max(numbers) is greater than 6" which returns the entire rows for those records.

Thank for reading

Comment: [quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html): "*searching for specific array elements can be a sign of database misdesign. Consider using a separate table with a row for each item that would be an array element. This will be easier to search, and is likely to scale better for a large number of elements*"

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from foos
where (select MAX(number) from unnest(numbers) number) > 6;
```

[online sample](http://rextester.com/GQFJ95586)

Comment: Nice, though that's not exactly what I'm looking for. Your query displays a row for _each element_ in the numbers array that is above six. I'm hoping to display just the row with `id` of 2 in this case.

Comment: So simple. Thanks!